# Is there a version of Burnside's lemma for a continuous set $X$?

Tags: group-theory

[Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma) counts orbits - distinct object up to some equivalence relation defined by a group $G$. If $X$ is a discrete set, and $G$ is a group, then the number of orbits $X_G$ is given by
$$ X_G\cdot |G|=\sum_{g\in G} |X^g|$$
where $X^g= \{x\in X : g x =x\}$ is the number of fixed point by $g$.

I wonder if there is a continuous version for this lemma, i.e., a version for continuous set $X$. In which case |X| may denote maybe the volume of $X$ or something similar.

Comment: What is a *continuous* set?

Comment: maybe I am abusing definitions, I mean for example $X=\mathbb{R}$ or $X=[0,1]^n$, etc.

Comment: Burnside lemma has no conditions on $X$, aside from $G$ acting on it. Also you need to either divide right part or multiple left by $|G|$.

Comment: I am not sure if this counts as a duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3765508/infinite-burnside-lemma  but the sole comment gives a highly relevant reference.

Comment: @mihaild Thank you for both the comment (I edited my question to add the missing $|G|$) and the answer. I deduced that $X$ must be discrete since in the proof (which I read on Wiki) I saw that they take a sum over $x\in X$. Is there another version of the proof? Also, what will $|X^g|$ mean in case of a connected set $X$, e.g., $X=\{x:x\in[0,1]^n\}$?